# How I can prevent ‘connection reset by peer’ in curl caused by server closing the socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, curl

I made a basic http server (I am developing my own because I want to do low level http analysis & manipulation in a later stage):

```
import socket
import threading
import queue
import time

class SocketServer:
    """
        Basic Socket Server in python
    """

    def __init__(self,host,port,max_theads):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server_socket = self.__initSocket()
        self.max_theands = max_theads
        self.request_queue = queue.Queue()        

    def __initSocket(self):
        return socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


    def __accept(self):
        self.server_socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            client_socket, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()    
            self.request_queue.put((client_socket, client_address))


    def __handle(self):
        while True:
            # Dequeue a request and process it
            client_socket, address = self.request_queue.get()    

            # Read HTTP Request
            # Log Http Request
            # Manipulate Http Request
            # Forward or respond

            client_socket.sendall(b"""HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n""");
;
            time.sleep(1)
            client_socket.close()
            self.request_queue.task_done()


    def __initThreads(self):
        for _ in range(self.max_theands):
            threading.Thread(target=self.__handle, daemon=True).start()


    def start(self):
        self.server_socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.__initThreads()
        self.__accept()
```

And I launch it into a seperate process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
1. Read settings
2. Bootstrap Manupilator
3. Bootstrap Control Panel

"""
import multiprocessing
from manipulator.http_socket_server import SocketServer

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # @todo read settings file
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 80
    max_threads = 5

    server = SocketServer(host, port, max_threads)
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=server.start)
    server_process.start()

    # Add other main application code here if needed

    server_process.join()
```

But curl receives:

```
curl 10.0.0.2
<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

despite the delay in `__handle`:

```
            time.sleep(1)
```

How I can close the socket gracefully?

Comment: ‘Connection reset by peer’ is not a timeout, and it is caused most probably by application errors in the server or client, typically closing a socket without having read all the incoming data. In this case clearly the server has not read the entire client request, or indeed any of it. NB the sleep is literally a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix is to send the content length header:

```py
content = '<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n'.encode()
headers = f'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {len(content)}\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'.encode()
client_socket.sendall(headers + content)
```

After change (and using port 8080):

```
C:\>curl localhost:8080
<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
```

Full working example:

```py
import socket
import threading
import queue

class SocketServer:
    def __init__(self, host, port, max_theads):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server_socket = self.__initSocket()
        self.max_theands = max_theads
        self.request_queue = queue.Queue()

    def __initSocket(self):
        return socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def __accept(self):
        self.server_socket.listen()
        while True:
            client_socket, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
            self.request_queue.put((client_socket, client_address))

    def __handle(self):
        while True:
            client_socket, address = self.request_queue.get()
            content = '<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n'.encode()
            headers = f'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {len(content)}\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'.encode()
            client_socket.sendall(headers + content)
            client_socket.close()
            self.request_queue.task_done()

    def __initThreads(self):
        for _ in range(self.max_theands):
            threading.Thread(target=self.__handle, daemon=True).start()

    def start(self):
        self.server_socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.__initThreads()
        self.__accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 8080
    max_threads = 5
    server = SocketServer(host, port, max_threads)
    server.start()
```